# Port forwarding to windows rdp

Tags: port-forwarding

I need assistance with a port forwarding related problem.

```
ssh root@adress.com -p2222 -L 3389:192.168.0.10:3389
```

Have to connect to this 192.168.0.10 ip via rdp standard port from my windows machine. I got the linux command which should work but I just don't know how to use it properly in windows via putty?

Answer (score 0):

The same way:

```
putty root@address.com -p 2222 -L 3389:192.168.0.10:3389
```

From the PuTTY GUI:

1. Go to *Connection* → *SSH* → *Tunnels*
2. Enter `3389` as "Source port"
3. Enter `192.168.0.10:3389` as "Destination"
4. Select "Local" and "Auto"
5. Click "Add"
6. Go back to *Session*
7. Enter `root@address.com:2222` as "Host Name"

From command line only:

```
plink root@address.com -p 2222 -L 3389:192.168.0.10:3389 -v -N
```

(`-v -N` are optional, they just enable verbose logging.)

Comment: Side note: Why are you connecting as root? **Don't be lazy and create a regular account.**

Comment: thanks mate, i thot i could do it via ssh tunnel but just not exactly, big help thx! root just for testing purpose. so now i should be able to reach adress 192.168.0.10:3389 via rdp on windows right? doesnt work tho  :_

Comment: No, that's not how SSH connection forwarding works. The client listens on the specified port on _localhost_ and when you connect to `localhost:3389`, it asks the server to connect to `192.168.0.10:3389`.